# ajax post external php file return always false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

my ajax code is :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://www.mp3-y.com/yt_output.json?vid=d9o8FCl4HOk",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
            alert("Success");
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error");
            }

        });
</script>
```

PHP Code is :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arr=array("Download" => "http://www.exemple.com/file");
$json = json_encode($arr);
print_r($json);
```

when i call the external php file i get always error!

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: No, I cannot test your code. *Press the F12 key and prepare to be amazed."*

Comment: Open the Developer Tools and see what error message you are getting in the Console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers will not allow your javascript to issue a XHR call to another domain (mp3-y.com) unless they allow it by specifying a specific header. Research "same origin policy".

If you can change your php code, you can add this header to allow anyone to call this API:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
?>
```

Comment: If your ajax code is running on the same domain, then my answer is not relevant.

Comment: i'm adding this line but nothing is changed

Comment: I edited the code to include all domains (*), try again please.

Comment: thank you for your reply but nothing was changed after add this line with *